# Xcode: Auto layout is shrinking my view

Tags: xcode

I'm having an issue with autolayout. In my storyboard it looks like this:

[image]

However, when I run the app, my simulator looks like this:

[image]

How do I get rid of the space on the bottom? My buttons get all squished in the simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do "add all missing constrains" it is on bottom right there is a button to do that see if it resolve

Comment: it's disabled. i don't have any warnings about that

Comment: Because if you see you dont have any constrains to the bottom you only have to the size of the images